# ios unzip limits using ZipArchive

Tags: ios, php-ziparchive

Does anyone know if there is a filesize limit with ZipArchive in iOS?

I am using it to unzip files to my Documents folder and it works perfect with a 65 Mb file and under but it crashes with a 125 Mb file. The files are similar in directory structure and number of files inside. I'm using an iPad 1 with iOS 4.3.

Comment: There is a memory limit (RAM), do you hold the content in the RAM?

Comment: I create a temp.zip file once downloaded

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, my application needs to decompress about 200 files. Unfortunately unable to unzip only about 100. It seems that the problem is not related to the size of the file, but the number of files. The strange thing is that if I launch the application directly from xCode (Run) everything works perfectly!
ZipArchive not return errors.
I'm using an iPad 3, ios 6.0, xcode 4.6